# Ansible でコントロールノードに対する命令の実行を行うには？

Tags: python, ansible

Ansibleにおける命令の実行先は基本的にインベントリファイル内に記載されたターゲットノードが対処になると考えております。
例えば、copyモジュール等でパスを指定する際にもターゲットノード上のパスを指定する必要がある認識です。

このような命令をコントロールノード(Ansibleがインストールされたサーバ)自体に実行するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

[ローカルのPlaybook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9_ja/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#playbook)で説明されています。`delegate_to: localhost`で実行先をlocalhostに変えるとかですかね。